# Create custom field for users to check if they agreed to terms

Tags: login

We have a employee center on our site.  We have used multiple plugins to create an employee center.  I have added a field to the database of "agreed".  This field holds a 1 or 0 if they have agreed to the employee terms of use.  I am trying to figure out if I can access this using the existing wordpress functions or not.  If not any help on updating this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: how have you added a field? note that WordPress already has a user meta table and associated functions for something like this.

Comment: I can move it if needed but I just added the field to the wp_users table.